# GUI broken after update to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, gui

I updated to Ubuntu 12.10 using the Update Manager in Ubuntu. ("A new version is available ...")
GRUB was broken and I think I managed to fix this but still the Graphical output looks super weired: (The Unity sidebar is lost and I had to start firefox through the terminal [STRG]+[ALT]+[T])

[image: Screenshot of broken GUI]

I already tried some apt-get with fglrx, gdm & ubuntu-desktop but nothing changed.

Graphics card: Mobility Radeon HD 2600

Comment: Please, tell us your Graphics Card model name (HD 4550 for example).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please provide additional information only by editing your question and not within a comment. Comments might/will eventually be deleted and so your information would get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graphics card is no longer officialy supported. You have these options:

**a) Use 12.04 with fglrx (precise x and kernel stack)**

**b) Use 12.10 with OSS drivers**

**c) Use PPA for 12.10 that enables fglrx installation to 12.10 with old AMD graphics**

If you'll choose option c, follow this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
sudo reboot
```

AMD decided to put all its graphics cards without DirectX11 support to "Legacy" state. This means they aren't going to add support for new xserver and linux kernel versions. PPA mentioned above installs git version of xserver, which is fully compatible with legacy fglrx and patched fglrx for compatibility with Quantal Linux kernel.

Comment: thx, this fixed it.
Though am I able to update to 13.04 without problems?

Comment: If you are using that ppa, you should wait (i've looked at it and it doesn't have fglrx-legacy right now).

Comment: Jup, I am using the makson96/fglrx ppa. Will this possibly be available anytime?